# Cytoscape.js lifecycle(?) issues when iterating through edge.data() for editing

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm working on a feature to edit an edge's data in Cytoscape.js. I have the same for editing a node's data, and it's working perfectly! But when I try to do the same for an edge, it doesn't.

**Chrome**: 70.0.3538.110

**Cytoscape.js**: 3.2.16

**Node.js**: 8.10.0

**Angular**: 6.1.2

Here's my simplified code:

Node editing:

```
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off">
  <div *ngFor="let field of buildDisplaySet(selectedElement) | keyvalue" class="search-input">          
  <label>
      {{field.key}}
  </label><br/>
  <input [name]="field.key"
         title="{{field.key}}"
         [value]="field.value"
         [(ngModel)]="field.value"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

This form iterates over the `selectedElement` (in this case a Cytoscape node)'s key/value pairs in `node.data()`, and creates an `input` field for each. When live, this template is rendered only once and allows for editing the values in the input fields (as expected).

Now, my attempt to do the same for a Cytoscape edge is exactly the same:

1. Get the key/value pairs for `edge.data()` through `buildDisplaySet()`
2. Put each key/value pair into an `input` element

When live, and dealing with edges, the above template renders, but is constantly recalculated in the browser such that I can't highlight an input or enter a new value.

Here are some screenshots of the console:

[Working node data template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Qo2.png)

[Constantly recalculating edge data template, that won't let me focus on input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQDMQ.png)

I thought that maybe it had something to do with the way edges are drawn on the Cytoscape canvas (hence my lifecycle(?) in the title), but I'm at an absolute loss as to why it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This situation was related to the custom pipe we were using and NOT anything Cytoscape.js related!! Thank you for looking anyway!